# Unable to start Cassandra Daemon 1.2.4 with Java 8

Tags: java, cassandra, eclipse-virgo

Hi I am using Cassandra 1.2.4 with Java 8(moving on from 7) as a service .I can run cassandra as a standalone process without any hassle, however  when I use it with an Apache Virgo application(3.7.0.D-20150114193621) it fails. 
Following is the output in the status.out log file and nothing in the system.log.

```
+ case "$1" in
+ echo 'Checking status of Cassandra daemon......'
Checking status of Cassandra daemon......
+ is_running
++ get_cass_pid
+++ ps -fC java
+++ grep -w org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon
+++ head -n 1
+++ awk '{print $2}'
++ echo
+ pid=
+ '[' x = x ']'
+ return 1
+ stat=1
+ case "$stat" in
+ echo 'Cassandra is not running'
Cassandra is not running
+ exit 1
```

I only get the below stacktrace in the virgo logs:

```
ERROR     TaskExec-1-thread-8      DE0005I Failed to start cassandra service
```

Since, it can run fine as a standalone process, there is no issue with setting the $CASSANDRA_HOME,$CLASSPATH or other variables.
I have verified the API call from the application and looks like its not able to start the daemon. Also,any information relating to the cassandra logging will be helpful to debug.

Comment: what's in the cassandra system.log? usually found at /var/log/cassandra/system.log

Comment: I found nothing from an application perspective, the logs written to this file were from starting cassandra as a standlone process.